# is $(x+y,x-y)$ a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y] $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is  $ I=(x+y,x-y)$ a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$

Since $x+y, x-y \in \mathbb{Z}$, therefore $(2x,2y) \in (x+y, x-y)$, and this implies that in $R=\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x,y]}{(x-y,x+y)}$, we have $2x=0$. But neither $2$ nor $x$ is zero in $R$. This shows that R is not an integral domain, which implies that $I$ is not a prime ideal.

Comment: What are $x, y$ in terms of $X, Y$?

Comment: oh, they are the same.

Comment: You should try to have consistent notations

Comment: I thought its written that way, that is why I did it, I can fix that.

Comment: It's written one way or the other. In $\Bbb Z[X,Y]$ you have elements like $5+3X-8X^2Y$ and ideals like $(X-Y)$, while in $\Bbb Z[x,y]$ you have elements like $5+3x-8x^2y$ and ideals like $(x-y)$.

Comment: Alright, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea of the proof is good, and everything seems correct. However, I would personally prefer some more justification of the statement that neither $2$ nor $x$ are zero in $R$. Or, equivalently (and a bit easier in my opinion), why they aren't in $(x+y,x-y)$ as elements of $\Bbb Z[x,y]$. Because in general, this is not easy to just *see*, and it's not always that easy to spot whether it's easy to see. So being thorough just for safety's sake is usually a good thing.

For instance, you have evaluation homomorphisms $\Bbb Z[x,y]\to \Bbb Z$. The evaluation at $(0,0)$ takes any element in the ideal to $0$ (no element of the ideal has a constant term), but doesn't take $2$ to $0$, so $2$ isn't in the ideal. And the evaluation homomorphism at $(1,1)$ takes any element in the ideal to an even number (no element in the ideal has an odd sum of coefficients), but takes $x$ to $1$, so $x$ can't be in the ideal either.

Comment: I think you are probably right, I should have given more justification as to why 2 and x don’t belong in the ideals. Thank you very much for your answer.