# Is the ideal $I=(X-Y, X+Y) $ in the polynomial ring $ \mathbb{Z} [X,Y]$ a prime ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Is the ideal $I=(X-Y, X+Y) $ in the polynomial ring $ \mathbb{Z} [X,Y]$ a prime ideal? Does replacing $ \mathbb{Z} [X,Y]$ by $ \mathbb{C} [X,Y]$ affect the nature of the given ideal?

---

**My Attempt**

---

As for any commutative ring with unity, $ R$ and and its ideal $I$, the quotient ring $ R/I$ is an integral domain iff $I$ is a prime ideal in $R$.
Here using ring isomorphism theorems,  the quotient ring
$ \mathbb{Z}[X,Y]/ (X-Y,X+Y) $   is  isomorphic to the quotient ring $ \mathbb{Z}[X]/ (2X) $. I was not able to proceed further.
Is the ideal $ I= (X-Y, X+ Y) $ is same as the ideal $ (X, Y)$ in $ \mathbb{Z} [X,Y] $?

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not prime. $2X=(X-Y)+(X+Y)$ but $X,2$ do not belong to the ideal.

Over the complex numbers (or any field $k$ of characteristic $\ne 2$) the ideal contains $x$ and $y$.The ideal then consists of all polynomials with constant term $0$. It is a prime ideal but the factor ring is a field isomorphic to $k$.

Comment: I did not notice the second half.Just added a solution.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3213146/305862).

Answer (score 1):

Using your quotient description, you can see right away that $2*X=0$, but neither $2$ nor $X$ is zero in the quotient, so that the ring has zero divisors. A quotient by a prime is an integral domain and would not have zero divisors, so it isn’t a prime ideal.

In the case of $\mathbb C$ or any field not or characteristic $2$, the same work gets you to $\mathbb C[X]/(2X)$, but now you can divide by $2$ and so the ideal is $X$, which leaves you with just $\mathbb C$. That is a field, so you must have quotiented by a maximal, hence prime, ideal.