# Show that in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$, $\langle x+y,x-y\rangle\subsetneq\langle x,y\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals, multivariate-polynomial

I have shown that in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$,
$$\langle x,y\rangle=\langle x+y,x-y\rangle,$$
by stating that
$$\{x,y\}\subset\langle x+y,x-y\rangle$$
because both $x$ and $y$ can be written as elements of the latter;
$$x=\frac{1}{2}(x+y)+\frac{1}{2}(x-y), \quad y=\frac{1}{2}(x+y)-\frac{1}{2}(x-y).$$ (The other direction is pretty trivial). 
I think that simply saying $1/2\notin \mathbb{Z}$ is not good enough of an argument to show that $\langle x+y,x-y\rangle\subsetneq\langle x,y\rangle \text{in } \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$, because what if there is *another way* to write $x$ as an element of $\langle x+y,x-y\rangle$ ? 
I have tried proving that assuming  $x \in \langle x+y,x-y\rangle$  leads to a contradiction (mainly by taking the degrees of the polys), but I haven't had any success. Help?

Comment: For a less direct approach, you could use [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3816203/is-the-ideal-i-x-y-xy-in-the-polynomial-ring-mathbbz-x-y-a-prime). If you show that $\langle x,y \rangle$ is prime, but $\langle x+y, x-y \rangle$ is not, then the two ideals must not be equal.

Comment: Hint: they're distinct $\!\bmod y-x\!:\,\ (2x,0) \subsetneq (x,x)\ $ using $\,y\equiv x\ \ $

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the homomorphism $\phi:\Bbb Z[x,y]\to\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ given by $\phi(x)=\phi(y)=1$.
Then $\langle x+y,x-y\rangle\subseteq\ker\phi$ but
$\langle x,y\rangle\not\subseteq\ker\phi$.

Comment: Thank you! Very elegant solution, but is there a more "mundane" way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to show it using 'mundane' methods as follows.

Suppose there exist $f(x,y), g(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ such that $x = (x+y)f + (x-y)g$. Observe that $f \neq g$, otherwise you factor $x = (2x)f$ and no way you can get rid of the $2$. Then this can be rewritten as $x = x(f+g) + y(f-g)$, and then we relabel this as $x = x \cdot h(x,y) + y \cdot k(x,y)$ for $h, k \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$, with $h = f+g, k = f-g$. Note that $k(x,y) = f - g \neq 0$.

Now, it is clear that the constant term of $h(x,y)$ must be 1, because there is no other way for $x$ term to appear on the RHS. But recall that $h(x,y) = f(x,y) +g(x,y)$. Thus, the constant term of $f + g$ is 1. But then the constant term of $f-g$ cannot be zero! (because of constant terms of f and g sum to one, and their difference is zero, you can solve to show that the constant terms are both equal 0.5). Then, if we look back at the equation $x = x \cdot (f+g) + y \cdot (f-g)$, we see that this must be a contradiction, because on the RHS there is a term $y \cdot (\text{const term of }f-g)$ which cannot be cancelled out by anything.